# Get git not to ignore directory after wildcard ignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following in my `.gitignore`:

```
*
!.gitignore
!.gitconfig
!.vimrc
!.bash/
!README.md
```

I would like git to track everything in that `.bash/` directory, but it seems to be ignoring it, but tracking everything else. I have also tried `!.bash/*`, but that didn't work. What's the trick to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `.gitignore` inside `.bash` with `!*`.

Note: `*` here means anything in the directory hierarchy will be excluded. Except the names which are included below.
If that is not your intention and you want `.bash/` like behaviour for other directories as well then you should consider using `/*`.

e.g.

```
/*
!.gitignore
!.gitconfig
!.vimrc
!.bash/
!README.md
!otherDirectory/
```